# ImproperlyConfigured: Django issue with local_settings and settings

Tags: python, django, windows

I'm trying to run a simple test for a django project and separate them in two files because it's a good practice, however, this always gives me an error

`ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "`

and I don't why I have this in my `settings.py` in the end

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except:
    pass
```

and only have this in my `local_settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

and yes there are in the same directory. I am using python3, windows 10

Traceback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\prueba\prueba\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\prueba\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\prueba\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\prueba\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\prueba\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\prueba\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 83, in handle
        executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
      File "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\prueba\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 20, in __init__
        self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
      File "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\prueba\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 52, in __init__
        self.build_graph()
      File "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\prueba\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 209, in build_graph
        self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
      File "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\prueba\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
        self.ensure_schema()
      File "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\prueba\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
        if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
      File "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\prueba\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 254, in cursor
        return self._cursor()
      File "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\prueba\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py", line 20, in complain
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

**EDIT**

This fix it

local_settings

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

DEBUG = True
```

and add this to the end of settings if you deploy this to heroku

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config()}

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Comment: Remove the `try`/`except` and see what happens... If something's going wrong - you're completely ignoring it and suppressing any useful debug info.

Comment: give the same error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.` @JonClements

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 the relative import should be

```
from .local_settings import *
```

Comment: Try removing the try.. except as Jon suggested

Comment: Same, what I answer him

Comment: I can't spot any other problems in the code you have posted.

Comment: I don't know why that gives error, thanks for the help, really appreciate <3